# Azure Web App - HTTP time out

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

After a deploy to our Azure Web App, we are getting 500 timeouts on any request to the service:

> 500 - The request timed out.
>
> The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

This has come out of the blue and we cannot determine what's causing it. It seems to take around 230s consistently to time out.

I've enabled all the diagnostic logs in the portal:

[image: Azure Logs Settings]

But I honestly don't quite know what to look for in the logs. I've scoured through all the files in the following folders but nothing jumps out.

[image: LogFiles]

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: was it working fine when you tested it locally ? does the service try to fetch  any initial data from a db and is that failing may be ?

Comment: Even plain HTML pages have the same problem.  This code works in our Azure-hosted DEV environment (which is configured exactly the same).

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please include the UTC time of one such failed request.

Comment: @DavidEbbo: I have gone the indirect route. The web app is named "davenewzastackoverflow". You will find two other web apps in that same app service... neither are working, but the one named "tran..." will be easiest to troubleshoot because I can give you a direct URI to some static html page (if that even helps). The following URI can be used: http://tran....azurewebsites.net/docs/default.html. I made a request timing out at around 17:17:15 UTC (after 230s). Thank you!!

Comment: To be more explicit, 2016-06-17 17:17:15 UTC.

Comment: So this is a Core RC1 app, right? Did you just deploy to it? Via VS?

Comment: @DavidEbbo: Correct. Deployed using the method as described in the PublishAspnetWebsite.ps1 file from [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114968/discussion-between-david-ebbo-and-davenewza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to get debug messages is to set `stdoutLogFile="D:\home\LogFiles\stdout.log"` in your config, instead of the `..\logs` path that you had. After changing that, you get an error file under `D:\home\LogFiles`. Here is the error you get:

`Application startup exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: SMTP server password cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: smtpPassword
   at TransitApi.Infrastructure.Modules.Logging.EmailOutput.EmailLogger..ctor(String recipient, String sender, String smtpUsername, String smtpPassword, String smtpHost, Int32 smtpPort, String environmentName, LogLevel minimumLevel)
   at TransitApi.Infrastructure.Modules.Logging.EmailOutput.EmailLoggerProvider.CreateLogger(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.AddProvider(ILoggerProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.AddProvider(ILoggerProvider provider)
   at TransitApi.Api.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)`

So some kind of issue setting up the mail server. That causes the process to crash, and that it behaves poorly.

But I highly suggest that you upgrade to Core RC2, as RC1 is quite obsolete.

Comment: I really appreciate the assistance here... especially since this was my own application error. Yes, we will probably jump straight from RC1 to RTM (via RC2 I'm sure) next week when RTM is expected.

Comment: Question: why does this time out and not break immediately?

Comment: Because error handling in RC1 sucks! :) I *think* it's better in RC2.

Comment: OK. Looking forward to RTM. It has been a long road!